# Texture baking averaging all colours (I think)

Tags: texturing, baking

So I'm making a raft using blender that's going to be exported to Unity, so I have to bake all my materials into textures. However, I'm struggling to bake the the textures. I'm using cycles baking on diffuse, into a image (single, sRGB) but when I bake the image it seems like it averages the colours together onto the texture. I've searched for a while and haven't found anyone with the same issue as myself so help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

(I'm on blender 3.2 if anyone is wondering)

[image]

[image: Baked image result][image: Log of raft]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to come from your *UV Map* node that is before the *Noise Texture* and that is set to *From Instancer*, you don't have any instancer so it may bug the bake:

[image]